# CAShapeLayer: Finding the intersected area of 3 circles

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, calayer

I have two questions:

1. Is there any way, in CALayer, to know if two circles are intersecting?
2. With three circles intersecting each other, is there any way to highlight the intersected area?

I am using CAShapeLayer to draw my circles:

```
- (CAShapeLayer *)circleForRadius:(CGFloat)iRadius withColor:(CGColorRef)iColor andDashPattern:(BOOL)isDashPattern {
CAShapeLayer *aSignalcircle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
aSignalcircle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0 * iRadius, 2.0 * iRadius) cornerRadius:iRadius].CGPath;
aSignalcircle.position = CGPointMake(0.0 - iRadius, 0.0 - iRadius);
aSignalcircle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
aSignalcircle.strokeColor = iColor;
aSignalcircle.lineWidth = kPSSignalStrokeWidth;

if (self.enableShadow) {
    aSignalcircle.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    aSignalcircle.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    aSignalcircle.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0.25);
    aSignalcircle.shadowRadius = 0.5;
}

if (isDashPattern) {
    aSignalcircle.lineDashPattern = @[@1, @1];
}

return aSignalcircle;
```

}

I tried clipping the context path using the below code but the output is not coming as expected:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat iRadius = 20.0;
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CAShapeLayer *aSignalcircle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    aSignalcircle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0 * iRadius, 2.0 * iRadius) cornerRadius:iRadius].CGPath;
    aSignalcircle.position = CGPointMake(10.0 , 10.0);
    aSignalcircle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    aSignalcircle.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    aSignalcircle.lineWidth = 1.0;
    CGContextAddPath(context, aSignalcircle.path);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CAShapeLayer *aSignalcircle1 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    aSignalcircle1.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0 * iRadius, 2.0 * iRadius) cornerRadius:iRadius].CGPath;
    aSignalcircle1.position = CGPointMake(30.0 , 10.0);
    aSignalcircle1.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    aSignalcircle1.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    aSignalcircle1.lineWidth = 1.0;
    CGContextAddPath(context, aSignalcircle1.path);
    CGContextClip(context);


    CAShapeLayer *aSignalcircle2 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    aSignalcircle2.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0 * iRadius, 2.0 * iRadius) cornerRadius:iRadius].CGPath;
    aSignalcircle2.position = CGPointMake(25.0 , 30.0);
    aSignalcircle2.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    aSignalcircle2.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    aSignalcircle2.lineWidth = 1.0;
    CGContextAddPath(context, aSignalcircle2.path);

    [[UIColor grayColor] set];
    CGContextFillPath(context);

// Temp addition to see how the circles are looking on screen
    [self.layer addSublayer:aSignalcircle];
    [self.layer addSublayer:aSignalcircle1];
    [self.layer addSublayer:aSignalcircle2];
}
```

I output is looking like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second question, you can use the following code to highlight the intersected area:

```
// Add first path and clip
CGContextAddPath(context, circle1.path);
CGContextClip(context);

// Add second path and clip
CGContextAddPath(context, circle2.path);
CGContextClip(context);

// Add third path and draw it. This means it'll be drawn within the clipping area
CGContextAddPath(context, circle3.path);
[[UIColor redColor] set];
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Comment: Good answer, I didn’t think about using clipping to draw the area. I was trying to find the intersection points and then drawing the arcs into a path. Your solution is clever.

Comment: I have tried clipping the context but it is not coming as expected. Please see the updated question. Please advise.

Comment: Currently, the position of the path is different from the position of its layer. You can try to comment out the lines that change layer positions and change the position of the path itself instead and it should work.

Comment: I got it. But when I do not change my layer positions all the three circles gets drawn with center as (0,0). Shall I do it via CGContextRef instead?

Comment: You should change the position of the path itself. For example: `aSignalcircle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 2.0 * iRadius, 2.0 * iRadius) cornerRadius:iRadius].CGPath;
    // aSignalcircle.position = CGPointMake(10.0 , 10.0);`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the radius of the two circles, and their centers, is very easy to know if they intersect each other:

```
// Supposing the layers have the circles at their center,
// which reading your code, it looks like it.
// Obtaining this values might be simpler in your code.
CGPoint center1 = circleLayer1.position;
CGPoint center2 = circleLayer2.position;
CGFloat radius1 = circleLayer1.bounds.size.width / 2.f;
CGFloat radius2 = circleLayer2.bounds.size.width / 2.f;

// Squared distance between the two circle centers
CGFloat distance2 = (center2.x - center1.x) * (center2.x - center1.x);
distance2 += (center2.y - center2.y) * (center2.y - center2.y);

// Squared sum of the two radii
CGFloat sumRadii2 = (radius1 + radius2) * (radius1 + radius2);

// The will intersect if the sum of the radii is larger than the distance)
BOOL intersection = sumRadii2 >= distance2;
```

About the intersection area… well, that’s harder. I suppose a good review of your geometry books will be necessary.

**Update:**

Building on your solution and Hejazi’s.

The path coordinates you are creating are relative to each of the layer, so before you can intersect them, you need to transform them to draw them in the right place:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat iRadius = 20.0;
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CAShapeLayer *aSignalcircle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    aSignalcircle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0 * iRadius, 2.0 * iRadius) cornerRadius:iRadius].CGPath;
    aSignalcircle.position = CGPointMake(10.0 , 10.0);
    aSignalcircle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    aSignalcircle.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    aSignalcircle.lineWidth = 1.0;

    // Add this line
    CGPathRef translatedPath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(aSignalcircle.path, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(aSignalcircle.position.x, aSignalcircle.position.y));

    CGContextAddPath(context, translatedPath);
    CGContextClip(context);

    // Release here
    CGPathRelease(translatedPath);

    CAShapeLayer *aSignalcircle1 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    aSignalcircle1.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0 * iRadius, 2.0 * iRadius) cornerRadius:iRadius].CGPath;
    aSignalcircle1.position = CGPointMake(30.0 , 10.0);
    aSignalcircle1.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    aSignalcircle1.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    aSignalcircle1.lineWidth = 1.0;

    // Same here
    translatedPath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(aSignalcircle1.path, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(aSignalcircle1.position.x, aSignalcircle1.position.y));
    CGContextAddPath(context, aSignalcircle1.path);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGPathRelease(translatedPath);    

    CAShapeLayer *aSignalcircle2 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    aSignalcircle2.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0 * iRadius, 2.0 * iRadius) cornerRadius:iRadius].CGPath;
    aSignalcircle2.position = CGPointMake(25.0 , 30.0);
    aSignalcircle2.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    aSignalcircle2.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    aSignalcircle2.lineWidth = 1.0;

    // And finally here
    CGPathRef translatedPath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(aSignalcircle2.path, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(aSignalcircle2.position.x, aSignalcircle2.position.y));
    CGContextAddPath(context, aSignalcircle2.path);
    CGPathRelease(translatedPath);

    [[UIColor grayColor] set];
    CGContextFillPath(context);

// Temp addition to see how the circles are looking on screen
    [self.layer addSublayer:aSignalcircle];
    [self.layer addSublayer:aSignalcircle1];
    [self.layer addSublayer:aSignalcircle2];
}
```

I haven’t tested, but that should position your paths in your new layer where the sublayers draw them. Tell me if it works.

Comment: I have tried clipping the context but it is not coming as expected. Please see the updated question. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Below piece of code worked:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat iRadius = 20.0;
    CGContextRef aContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    CAShapeLayer *aSignalcircle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    aSignalcircle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 2.0 * iRadius, 2.0 * iRadius) cornerRadius:iRadius].CGPath;
    aSignalcircle.lineWidth = 1.0;
    CGContextAddPath(aContext, aSignalcircle.path);
    CGContextClip(aContext);


    CAShapeLayer *aSignalcircle1 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    aSignalcircle1.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(30.0, 10.0, 2.0 * iRadius, 2.0 * iRadius) cornerRadius:iRadius].CGPath;
    aSignalcircle1.lineWidth = 1.0;

    CGContextAddPath(aContext, aSignalcircle1.path);
    CGContextClip(aContext);


    CAShapeLayer *aSignalcircle2 = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    aSignalcircle2.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(25.0, 30.0, 2.0 * iRadius, 2.0 * iRadius) cornerRadius:iRadius].CGPath;
    aSignalcircle2.lineWidth = 1.0;

    CGContextAddPath(aContext, aSignalcircle2.path);
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    CGContextFillPath(aContext);
}
```